# NPT used in U.S Pressure Gauges

Tags: plumbing

Is the NPT used in United States Pressure Gauges parallel or tapered?

The following is the unattached photo.

[image]

When I attached the adaptor which is NPT to BSP converter. It is not all the way when tightened, not even half. Is the Pressure gauge thread tapered and the adaptor parallel? Or vice versa? how do I tell?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[It's pipe thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_pipe_thread) - i.e. tapered, NPTM, unless you have an oddball gauge. Size depends on the gauge.

How do you tell? Measure it.

No idea what you have for an adaptor internal thread.

How have you "tightened" it - Hand tight? Using wrenches? Clearly not using pipe dope or teflon tape, one or the other of which is required to actually get a seal.

If you refer to the Wikipedia page linked, you'll note that 1/8 and 1/4 (likely typical sizes) have about 3 turns difference between "hand tight" and "effective thread length."

Comment: I hand tight it. Well if i use tool. Wont it deform the thread?

Comment: Only if you overdo it. The hexagonal sections of the fittings are there *precisely* for the use of wrenches on them. Learning about not tight enough, tight enough, and too tight is a difficult thing over the internet, so you might want to recruit some local help with experience in working with threaded fittings. Lacking that, just keep checking for leaks - *after* first using pipe dope or teflon tape on the male threads.

Comment: When you connect a pressure gauge. Is it supposed to be all the way with all threads engaged or only half?

Comment: There is no established tightening standard for NPT threaded components because the *mandatory* use of a thread sealant (e.g. tape, dope, combination of both, or even sometimes gauze with dope on large fittings) combined with the thread taper makes "tight enough" subjective. Rule of thumb is "nice and tight" using wrenches.

Comment: There are fittings that work hand tight - these are not those fittings...those typically seal with o-rings.